# Unit Testing Object Creation of Class with Hidden State (Query Object Pattern)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//query object pattern
public class FooQuery
{
    private string _startsWith;

    public FooQuery NameStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {
        _startsWith = startsWith;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Foo> Execute(IQueryable<Foo> someContext)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_startsWith))
            someContext = someContext.Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith(_startsWith));
        return someContext.ToList();
    }
}

public interface IFooService
{
    List<Foo> FindByNameStartsWith(string startsWith);
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooRepository _fooRepository;

    public FooService(IFooRepository fooRepository)
    {
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    public List<Foo> FindByNameStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {
        var query = new FooQuery().NameStartsWith(startsWith);
        return _fooRepository.Find(query);
    }
}

public interface IFooRepository
{
    List<Foo> Find(FooQuery query);
}

public class FooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public List<Foo> Find(FooQuery query)
    {
        var someContext = new List<Foo>().AsQueryable(); //would be EF/Mongo, etc
        return query.Execute(someContext);

    }
}
```

Basically, I have a service "FooService" that news up a query object "FooQuery" and sets its state based on method parameters passed to it. The service then passes the query to the repository "FooRepository" where it does its data access thing. FooQuery purposefully does not expose its state via properties. It instead exposes methods for greater control. I need to unit test that FooService has created the query object correctly.

This is a challenge because FooQuery's state is not visible for unit testing. I see a couple of options, but all seem to smell:

1. Expose the state of FooQuery as read-only properties and, in unit tests, check those properties are valid when passed to the repository. (Checking the state of the query is technically possible via mocking frameworks with callbacks.) I don't like this because we now have to open up the state and modify the code just for testing purposes.
2. Keep the code as is and test that the results generated from the service method are the same as the results from the query object. I don't like this because it makes the unit tests larger, less conclusive and more redundant (I'd have to have a very similar test for the query object itself when checking for results)
3. Wrap FooQuery in an interface and create a factory to be injected into foo service. I can then test the proper methods where called on a mocked query. But, that still leaves me with a challenging test for the factory itself.

Any suggestions for testing/re-factoring this code to make it easier to test would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `Equals` on `FooQuery` then validate I you get the expected `FooQuery` via a mock'ed `IFooRepository`. This is a limited form your option #1.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two responsibilities: getting an IQueryable from the datasource, and performing queries on it.  Perhaps a simpler design makes sense?

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
     IQueryable<Foo> GetFoo();
}

public FooService : IFooService
{
     public List<Foo> FindByNameStartsWith(string startsWith)
     {
          return new FooQuery().StartsWith(startsWith).Execute(_fooRepo.GetFoo());
     }
}
```

Now FooService is easy to test, and database specific logic is separated from all other logic.

```
[Test]
public void StartsWithFiltersFooFromRepository()
{
    var fooFromRepository = new List<Foo> { new Foo {Name="yes1"}, new Foo {Name="no"}, new Foo {Name="yes2"} };
    _fooRepMock.Setup(r=>r.GetFoo()).Returns(fooFromRepository);

    var actual = _fooService.FindByNameStartsWith("yes");

    Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(new [] { fooFromRepository[0], fooFromRepository[2] }));
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'd like to keep my querying logic within the FooQuery class, since it is re-used between other services.

Comment: If you like, you still can.  That feels like unnecessary complexity that will make your life harder, but you know your context best.  In that case, the test is exactly the same, and change the implementation to use a FooQuery.  I'll make appropriate edits.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'd argue that the query object pattern simplifies rather than makes things more complicated, because you are moving the responsibility of the query itself to this class. The service is just feeding the query values and coordinating with the repository. Exposing a GetAll() method --an IQueryable to your data source via the repo can open things up to problems in a larger system, since there's no constraints on the types of queries you can perform.